# Trigger.io forge.topbar.setTint() error

Tags: ios, module, ios7, native, trigger.io

I am trying to change colour of top and status bars like so:

```
forge.topbar.setTint([255,0,0,50], function() {
    console.log('Success!');
}, function(content) {
    console.log(content);
});
```

but it spits out the error:

```
"-[ForgeApp statusBarBox]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16638080"
```

I am using latest TopBar module Version: 2.2 and Toolkit version 2.0.1
It does not work on iOS7. Maybe this could be an issue?

Comment: I've also been able to reproduce this problem. I'm thinking a workaround might be to implement a html topbar and disable the native one, but obviously that sucks.

Comment: If you update tot he latest 2.03 for the core it seems to fix this but you will still have issues with the tabbar not working in ios6, trigger IO does not seem to want to address this issue as they have remained silent on all fronts

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem by upgrading the platform version to 2.0.3

It's marked as unstable however (2.0.1 is current stable) so YMMV.

I haven't had any crashes yet.

edit: I just saw proxim0 answered this in the comments an hour ago, too.